# JavaScript Join/Concat/Filter?

Tags: javascript

I am struggling on a solution, and I built this simple example.  I am hoping someone can jar my brain.  Thanks in advance.

```
var arr = [
{ name:"DOM", other: "a" },
{ name:"DEE", other: "b" },
{ name:"DEE", other: "c" },
{ name:"DEE", other: "d" },
{ name:"DEE", other: "e" },
];
```

Expected output:

```
{name: "DOM", other: "a" }
{name: "DEE", other: "b,c,d,e"}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far and what's not working about it?

Comment: Did you flag my question as needing to be deleted because "you" didn't understand it?

Comment: Unless you tag other people, I’m the only person notified by your message, and I didn’t flag your question (you should be able to see who flagged it in the blue banner above).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

this should works:

```js
let arr = [
    { name:"DOM", other: "a" },
    { name:"DEE", other: "b" },
    { name:"DEE", other: "c" },
    { name:"DEE", other: "d" },
    { name:"DEE", other: "e" },
];
result = {}
for(let item of arr){
    if(item.name in result){
        result[item.name] += ',' + item.other
    }else{
        result[item.name] = item.other
    }
}
let resultArray = Object.entries(result).map((data)=> 
    {return {name: data[0], other: data[1]}})

console.log(resultArray)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use `forEach` and build an object with key as `name` with values as agreegate `other`. Get `Object.values` from above object.

```js
var arr = [
  { name: "DOM", other: "a" },
  { name: "DEE", other: "b" },
  { name: "DEE", other: "c" },
  { name: "DEE", other: "d" },
  { name: "DEE", other: "e" },
];

const merge = (arr) => {
  const res = {};
  arr.forEach((item) => {
    if (item.name in res) {
      res[item.name].other += `,${item.other}`;
    } else {
      res[item.name] = { ...item };
    }
  });
  return Object.values(res);
};

console.log(merge(arr));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var arr = [
    { name: "DOM", other: "a" },
    { name: "DEE", other: "b" },
    { name: "DEE", other: "c" },
    { name: "DEE", other: "d" },
    { name: "DEE", other: "e" },
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, curr) => {
    if (acc[curr.name]) {
        acc[curr.name].other = acc[curr.name]['other'].concat(',' + curr.other)
    } else {
        acc[curr.name] = { name: curr.name, other: curr.other }
    }
    return acc;
}, {})

console.log(result)
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```